# Why is my calculation returning a result of 0 when the other identical one is in python

Tags: python-3.x, function

Windows, Spyder, Python 3.6

Hello, I am gradually working on this code and I keep getting null value for a calculation. I am performing the same calculation before it and when I print the variables by themselves they do not have null values. The code I am working on is below. The result I get when running the code is and ever changing value for the trd1() function but a 0.0 for trd2() function. I have looked for answers but cant seem to find any relevant ones?

```
import random

#define variables

amt1 = (1000)
amt2 = (1000)
prevAmt1 = ()
prevAmt2 = ()

#create random exchange rates
def exRt1():
    return round(random.random() * (1.399 - 1.001) + 1.001, 3) 

def exRt2():
    return round(random.random() * (0.999 - 0.699) + 0.699, 3)

#assign exchange rates to variables

rate1 = exRt1()
rate2 = exRt2()

#create a conversion function

def convert(amount, exchange_rate):
    return amount * exchange_rate

#create trade functions

def trd1(amount1,exRt2):
    trd1Amt = convert(amount1, exRt2())
    print(trd1Amt)
    return trd1Amt
trd1(amount1,exRt2)

def trd2(amount2,exRt1):
    trd2Amt = convert(amount2, exRt1())
    print(trd2Amt)
    return trd2Amt
trd1(amount2,exRt1)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What was the values for `amount1` and `amount2` [Link](https://repl.it/Jo41/3)

Comment: At least as shown, you aren't calling `trd2`; you are calling `trd1` twice.

Comment: There is still no [difference](https://repl.it/Jo41/4)

Comment: 1000 and 1000 were the values for amounts and i changed the trd1 second call to trd2 as it should have been but still getting amount 0.0

Comment: blah fixed idiot was sayng amount1 and 2 instead of amt1 and 2